# To-do app API made with Slim 3

Tags: php, sql, api, slim, php7

I have put together the back-end (API) with the Slim framework (v3) and MySQL.

[image]

In index.php I have:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Todos Routes
require '../src/routes/todos.php';

$app->run();
```

In `db.php` I have:

```
class db{
    // Properties
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'root';
    private $dbpass = '';
    private $dbname = 'todoapp';

    // Connect
    public function connect(){
            $mysql_connect_str = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname";
            $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $dbConnection;
    }
 }
```

In `todos.php` I have:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});

// Get Todos
$app->get('/api/todos', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM todos";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $todos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($todos);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

// Add Todo
$app->post('/api/todo/add', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $title = $request->getParam('title');
    $completed = $request->getParam('completed');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO todos (title, completed) VALUES (:title,:completed)";

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':completed',  $completed);

        $stmt->execute();
        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Todo Added"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

// Update Todo
$app->put('/api/todo/update/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $title = $request->getParam('title');
    $completed = $request->getParam('completed');

    $sql = "UPDATE todos SET
                title   = :title,
                completed   = :completed WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':completed',  $completed);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Todo Updated"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

// Delete Todo
$app->delete('/api/todo/delete/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $sql = "DELETE FROM todos WHERE id = $id";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Todo Deleted"}';
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

#### Questions/concerns:

1. Is the application well-structured or should I move the logic into
   controllers?
2. If I should move the logic into controllers, what would
   be the best approach to doing that?

#### Post scriptum

I have added the front-end of the application **[here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261363/178805)** for those that might be interested.

Comment: I have added the front-end of the application **[here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261363/178805)** if you're interested :)

Comment: Why do you catch all PDO exceptions? Why don't you implement an error handler for all exceptions or just use the built-in error handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Is the application well-structured or should I move the logic into controllers?

I agree with NemoXP that the current format is not well-structured. A file with 112 lines of code isn't horrible in terms of file length, but it handles multiple things - e.g. routing, updating models, etc. Separating the code out to controller methods would be wise - especially if multiple developers end up modifying the files.

> #### If I should move the logic into controllers, what would be the best approach to doing that?

As NemoXP stated: a controller would be a good solution for moving the logic out of the router - e.g. TodoController, with a method for each route. That could have methods to abstract common tasks like returning the JSON, exception handling, etc.

### Suggestions

#### Avoid re-assignment

> ```
>     // Get DB Object
>     $db = new db();
>     // Connect
>     $db = $db->connect();
> ```

With the first assignment `$db` is assigned an instance of class `db`. Then in the next assignment that same variable is assigned the return value from the method `connect`, which is an instance of `PDO`.

I likely mentioned in a review of your JavaScript code that it is wise to use `const` instead of `let` to avoid [accidental re-assignment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085). The concept applies here as well - over-writing a variable can make it difficult to "reason" about code if a variable changes type.

A better name for the variable in the second assignment would be something that illustrates that it is a connection, not a database - something like `$connection`, `$conn`, etc.

#### Limit data returned

> ```
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM todos";
> ```

For a small application this likely isn't an issue, especially if there are typically a small number of records and only a few columns. Problems can occur when:

- the table grows to have many columns - of course it isn't ideal but in real life it does happen. It is best to specify only the columns needed instead of `*`
- the number of rows grows to more than is necessary. This can lead to memory issues. It is best to limit the number of results instead of selecting all records
- the data isn't filtered- perhaps for this application there isn't a need to filter the data but in a larger application, it would be wise to add some conditions to limit the data returned.

#### Storing credentials and other details

> ```
> private $dbhost = 'localhost';
> private $dbuser = 'root';
> private $dbpass = '';
> private $dbname = 'todoapp';
> ```

These are things that should not be stored in a repository. It is wise to store them in a file that is ignored by the VCS - e.g. .env files, which can be included with packages like [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

#### Response Type

It appears that all routes return strings that are to be interpreted as JSON. In such cases it is appropriate to [add a header to describe the Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/1575353). While it likely isn’t a security hole anymore, [at one point ~15 years ago an XSS attack may have been possible if content-type headers weren’t set](http://jibbering.com/blog/?p=514).

```
$response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

Presuming all routes have that same type, the header could be added with the other headers (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-*`).

#### JSON String construction

In the route to get all TODO items `json_encode()` is used to convert the list to JSON format. Yet in other cases, included the `catch` blocks, a JSON object is created manually - e.g.

> ```
>   echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
> ```

This could be simplified using `json_encode()`

```
   echo json_encode('["error" => ["text” => $e->getMessage()]]];
```

The benefit here is no risk of the exception message breaking the string literal - e.g. if it contained a delimter character like `”` or `}`. Actually, now that I think of it, the original line could lead to a JavaScript error because the message is not surrounded by double quotes!

Comment: I have added the front-end of the application **[here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/261363/178805)** if you're interested :)

Answer (score 4):

1. In short, no. Actually doesn't seem to be structured in any way :D
2. If your API will be just that, you can even give up on slim and have a plain index.php with url rewrite so you can achieve the best performance.

Few things that I recommend:

- first, I would try to use a DI (dependency injection). I like php-di ( https://php-di.org/ )
- next would be to try to go with an mvc structure where the view is actually a JSON output: have some classes, TodoController, and multiple public methods (one for each action/route). Another approach would be to use Actions, as in symfony (basically would mean to have separate class files for each route: AddTodoAction.php,DeleteTodoAction.php).
- the, you should group your files and here we can debate a lot. I like to have a "Library" folder and inside that have one folder per each module and each module has it's own grouping (Controller / Model / Dao / Processor / Validator / etc. *). It's some sort of mix between having all controllers inside a single folder and grouping by business logic. If you only have Todo's without any users or any other relations, you can have a generic Controller/Action folder and keep all controllers/actions inside that folder.
- ideally to also use a orm for communicating with the database, or at least use bindings for all inputs ($id should also be considered an input). I use eloquent with slim ( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent ).
- have any sort of validation before actually using the input
- try and reuse the $response object that slim is already providing and avoid direct echo-ing the output as so.

You can also try to have a look over this: https://github.com/gurkanbicer/slimmvc

Extra: have you tried slim 4.8? Why start a new project on such an old version?

*: folder structure example:

```
config/
    bootstrap.php
    routes.php
    settings.php
public/
    index.php
src/
    Core/ (here I keep common middlewares for authentication, health checks or other things, maybe a way to format arrays / objects to json to output them properly)
    Library/
        Todo/
            Action/
                AddTodoAction.php (called from routes.php and should only validate input, call a method from service and the output the result)
                DeleteTodoAction.php
                ListTodoAction.php
            Model/
                Todo.php
                TodoDao.php (can keep it here or in a separate namespace: Src/Library/Todo/Dao/TodoDao.php )
            Validator/ (can go with same approach as for controller vs action: a single class for all routes or multiple classes separated per action / business logic)
                AddTodoValidator.php
                TodoValidator.php
            TodoService.php (the service is the only class that I call from other services. It has methods for controller, example: getTodo(), and it calls a DAO class for communication with database / execute queries)
tests/
    ... (if any)
```