# To-do app front-end in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, event-handling, vue.js

I have put together a *To-do Application* with the Slim framework on the back-end (API) and a Vue 3 front-end. I added a **[demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7eRMfdc8qM)** on my **YouTube** channel.

In the main **App.vue** file I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header 
    title="My todo list" 
    :unsolvedTodos = unsolvedTodos
    />

    <List 
      :todos="todos"
      :dataIsLoaded=dataIsLoaded
      @delete-todo="deleteTodo" 
      @toggle-todo="toggleTodo" />

    <Footer
      :isValidInput=isValidInput
      newTitle = ""
      placeholder= "+ Add new todo"
      validationMsg = "Please add at least 3 characters"
      @add-todo="addTodo"
      />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
import Header from './components/Header.vue'
import List from './components/List.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    List,
    Footer
  },

  data() {
    return {
      apiUrl: "http://todo.com/api",
      dataIsLoaded: false,
      isValidInput: true,
      todos: [],
      unsolvedTodos: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    showTodos: function(){
      axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.todos = response.data;
      })
     .then(this.getUnsolvedTodos)
     .then(this.dataIsLoaded = true);
    },

    getUnsolvedTodos: function(){
      this.unsolvedTodos = this.todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.completed == 0;
      });
    },

    toggleTodo: function(todo) {
      let newStatus = todo.completed == "0" ? 1 : 0;
      axios.put(`${this.apiUrl}/todo/update/${todo.id}`, {
        title: todo.title,
        completed: newStatus
      })
    },

    deleteTodo: function(id) {
      axios.delete(`${this.apiUrl}/todo/delete/${id}`)
    },

    addTodo: function(newTitle){
     const newToDo = {
        title: newTitle,
        completed: 0
      }
     
      if(newTitle.length > 2){
        this.isValidInput = true;
        axios.post(`${this.apiUrl}/todo/add`, newToDo);
      } else {
        this.isValidInput = false;
      }
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.showTodos();
  },

  watch: {
    todos() {
      this.showTodos();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In **Header.vue**:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
    <span class="count" :class="{zero: unsolvedTodos.length === 0}">{{unsolvedTodos.length}}</span>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: String,
    unsolvedTodos: Array
  },
}
</script>
```

In **Footer.vue**:

```
<template>
  <footer>
    <form @submit.prevent="addTodo()">
      <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="newTitle">
      <span class="error" v-if="!isValidInput">{{validationMsg}}</span>
    </form>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer',

  props: {
    placeholder: String,
    validationMsg: String,
    isValidInput: Boolean
  },

  data () {
    return {
     newTitle: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addTodo() {
      this.$emit('add-todo', this.newTitle)
      this.newTitle = ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The to-do list (List.vue):

```
<template>
  <transition-group name="list" tag="ul" class="todo-list" v-if=dataIsLoaded>
      <TodoItem v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
        :key="todo.id" 
        :class="{done: Boolean(Number(todo.completed)), current: index == 0}" 
        :todo="todo" 
        @delete-todo="$emit('delete-todo', todo.id)"
        @toggle-todo="$emit('toggle-todo', todo)"
        />
    </transition-group>
    <div class="loader" v-else></div>   
</template>

<script>
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem.vue";

export default {
  name: 'List',

  components: {
    TodoItem,
  },

  props: {
    dataIsLoaded: Boolean,
    todos: Array
  },

  emits: [
    'delete-todo',
    'toggle-todo'
  ]
}
</script>
```

The single to-do item (TodoItem.vue):

```
<template>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" :checked="Boolean(Number(todo.completed))" @change="$emit('toggle-todo', todo)" />
    <span class="title">{{todo.title}}</span>
    <button @click="$emit('delete-todo', todo.id)">
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
 </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TodoItem',

  props: {
    todo: Object
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Questions / concerns:

1. Is the application well-structured?
2. Could the code be significantly "shortened"?

Comment: Were you able to simplify the event passing using `v-bind="$attrs"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## Is the application well-structured?

On the whole it seems okay, though see the answer to the next question that means the structure could be slightly changed for the better.

> ## Could the code be significantly "shortened"?

### Simon Says: use computed properties

Like [Simon suggests: use computed properties](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260915/120114) - the implementation inside `getUnsolvedTodos()` could be moved to a computed property, with a `return` instead of assigning the result from calling `.filter()` to a data variable. Then there is no need to need to call that method and set up the property within the object returned by the `data` function.

### Promise callback consolidation

The call to `axios.get()` in `showTodos()` has multiple `.then()` callbacks:

> ```
> showTodos: function(){ 
>   axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`)
>     .then((response) => {
>       this.todos = response.data;
>     })
>    .then(this.getUnsolvedTodos)
>    .then(this.dataIsLoaded = true);
>   },
> ```

Those can be consolidated to a single callback - especially since none of them return a promise.

```
showTodos: function(){
  axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/todos`)
  .then((response) => {
    this.todos = response.data;
    this.getUnsolvedTodos(); //this can be removed - see previous section
    this.dataIsLoaded = true;
  });
},
```

While this does require one extra line, it would avoid confusion because somebody reading the code might think the statements passed to `.then()` should be functions that return promises.

### Single-use variables

In `toggleTodo` the variable `newStatus` is only used once so it could be consolidated into the object passed to the call:

```
axios.put(`${this.apiUrl}/todo/update/${todo.id}`, {
  title: todo.title,
  completed: todo.completed == "0" ? 1 : 0
})
```

If that variable is kept it could be created with `const` instead of `let` since it is never re-assigned.

### Passing events to parent

In `List.vue` the `<TodoItem` has these attributes:

> ```
> @delete-todo="$emit('delete-todo', todo.id)"
> @toggle-todo="$emit('toggle-todo', todo)"
> ```

Those seem redundant. In Vue 2 these lines could be replaced with a single line: [`v-on="$listeners"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) but apparently [that was removed with Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/listeners-removed.html). I tried replacing those lines with `v-bind="$attrs"` but it didn't seem to work - I will search for the VueJS 3 way to do this.

Comment: Any answer that says "Simon says" gets a +1 from me